# ShellScript does not run 'cd', calling sh in php

Tags: php, linux, shell

see if anyone has been there, I have this simple code in shellscript, which I access the folder (/home/teste4toquew5824) and then confirm if I entered the directory with pwd,

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/teste4toquew5824 && pwd
```

and I have a php file (located in /var/www/html) that calls this sh:

```
 $var= shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/api/teste.sh');
    echo "<br><br>";
    var_dump($var);
```

When I receive the return of the pwd it shows as if it still had in the directory of the php file (/var/ www/html), in other words it is not "accepting" or executing the cd command.

1 - I have already applied permissions for php and sh.

2 - I already confirmed the directory /home/teste4toquew5824 exists

3 - I have already tested and placed an echo inside the sh just to confirm that the php is calling and executing the sh correctly.

4 - I already put a line in sh to copy a file just to be sure that another command is being executed as well and copied the file to /var/www/html

5 - I tried change the bash in top to #!/bin/sh -

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you very much

Comment: Try changing dirs befor executing the script with `chdir(<path>)`

Comment: Shouldn't you want to do `shell_exec( 'cd /usr/local/bin/api/teste.sh && pwd' )`??

Comment: I tried now chdir and shell_exec( 'cd /usr/local/bin/api/teste.sh && pwd' ) but doesn't work, I think may relation with permissions

Comment: Is php running in chroot environment?

Comment: That's not shell script but bash script, see also the description of the `shell` tag that you applied. Also, this has nothing to do with Linux-specific APIs, so remove that one as well. That said, how do you even invoke all that code? Please try to extract and provide a [mcve], which also helps finding the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that the current working directory is a property of each process.  For this, the `cd` command is a command internal to the shell that the shell executes by making a call to the `chdir(2)` system call.

This means that the shell can change it's directory, and then fork several processes, that will inherit the working directory of the parent (the shell), but there's no way for the shell to be able to change the directory of the process that called it.  This is the reason you call a script (a shell process) that changes its directory, calls `pwd`, showing that the directory is actually the one you requested, but your own directory continues to be the same as before, as if the shell had ignored your command.

There's no system call to change the current directory of another process in posix systems, but the process to do it by itself.

Confusion arises from the fact that the `cd` command *looks like* other commands that are implemented in a different program, but the `cd` command is an internal command (you'll not see a `/bin/cd` command anywhere)